# PHP download only file with smallest ID number

Tags: php, mysql, download

I try approximately 30 tutorials how to download files from folder/mysql but nothing works in a way that I need. Then I come across [this one](http://www.2my4edge.com/2013/07/file-download-coding-using-php-and-mysql.html) and it helped me to some point.

This tutorial bring names from DB and click on that names download starts. I adjusted code to my needs so now every file in folder/mysql prints with name, download button and delete button, and name and delete number working fine but download button only download first file with smallest ID number.

Please, don't tell me that this is not secure because I need prepare statement or something like that because this is now for learning, and after I understand this I will change to be more secure.

This is my code:

**files.php**

```
<div class="row" style="display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">

<?php

    $query = "SELECT * FROM uploads ORDER BY filename ASC";
    $select_uploads = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_uploads)) {

    $id = $row['id'];
    $filename = $row['filename'];
    $filetype = $row['filetype'];
    $filesize = $row['filesize'];

?>

<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="thumbnail text-center">
        <div class="caption">
            <p class="filename"><small><?php echo $filename; ?></small></p>


<?php

    $fetc = "SELECT * FROM uploads LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $fetc);
    if(!$result) {
        die("QueryFailed" . mysqli_error($connection));
    }

while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $name=$row1['filename'];
    $type=$row1['filetype'];

?>

<p><a name="download" href="download.php?filename=<?php echo $name ;?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" role="button"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Preuzmi</a></p>

<?php 
} 
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="delete_file" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <?php
    echo '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" type="submit" name="delete" onClick=\'javascript: return confirm("Da li ste sigurni da želite da obrišete?"); \'><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Obriši</button>';
    ?>
</form>

</div>
</div>
</div>

<?php

}

?>

</div>


<?php

if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {

    $id = $_POST['delete_file'];

    if(isset($_SESSION['user_role'])) {

        if($_SESSION['user_role'] == 'admin' || $_SESSION['user_role'] == 'superadmin') {

            unlink("uploads/".$filename);
            $query = "DELETE FROM uploads WHERE id = {$id} ";
            $delete_filename = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
            header("Location: fajlovi.php");

        }

    }

}

?>
```

**download.php**

```
<?php
function output_file($file, $name, $mime_type='')
{
 if(!is_readable($file)) die('File not found or inaccessible!');
 $size = filesize($file);
 $name = rawurldecode($name);
 $known_mime_types=array(
    "htm" => "text/html",
    "exe" => "application/octet-stream",
    "zip" => "application/x-zip-compressed",
    "7z"  => "application/octet-stream",
    "doc" => "application/msword",
    "docx"=> "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
    "jpg" => "image/jpg",
    "php" => "text/plain",
    "xls" => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
    "xlsx"=> "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
    "ppt" => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
    "pptx"=> "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation",
    "gif" => "image/gif",
    "pdf" => "application/pdf",
    "txt" => "text/plain",
    "html"=> "text/html",
    "png" => "image/png",
    "jpeg"=> "image/jpg"
 );

 if($mime_type==''){
     $file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file,"."),1));
     if(array_key_exists($file_extension, $known_mime_types)){
        $mime_type=$known_mime_types[$file_extension];
     } else {
        $mime_type="application/force-download";
     };
 };

 //turn off output buffering to decrease cpu usage
 @ob_end_clean(); 

 // required for IE, otherwise Content-Disposition may be ignored
 if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
 ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
 header('Content-Type: ' . $mime_type);
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
 header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

 // multipart-download and download resuming support
 if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
 {
    list($a, $range) = explode("=",$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'],2);
    list($range) = explode(",",$range,2);
    list($range, $range_end) = explode("-", $range);
    $range=intval($range);
    if(!$range_end) {
        $range_end=$size-1;
    } else {
        $range_end=intval($range_end);
    }

    $new_length = $range_end-$range+1;
    header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content");
    header("Content-Length: $new_length");
    header("Content-Range: bytes $range-$range_end/$size");
 } else {
    $new_length=$size;
    header("Content-Length: ".$size);
 }

 /* Will output the file itself */
 $chunksize = 1*(1024*1024); //you may want to change this
 $bytes_send = 0;
 if ($file = fopen($file, 'r'))
 {
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
    fseek($file, $range);

    while(!feof($file) && 
        (!connection_aborted()) && 
        ($bytes_send<$new_length)
          )
    {
        $buffer = fread($file, $chunksize);
        echo($buffer); 
        flush();
        $bytes_send += strlen($buffer);
    }
 fclose($file);
 } else
 //If no permissiion
 die('Error - can not open file.');
 //die
die();
}
//Set the time out
set_time_limit(0);

//path to the file
$file_path='uploads/'.$_REQUEST['filename'];


//Call the download function with file path,file name and file type
output_file($file_path, ''.$_REQUEST['filename'].'', 'text/plain');
?>
```

I cut pretty much of code to be cleaner for you to see. Sorry for my bad english, I hope I explained the problem properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `files.php` module contains two nested queries. The first one fetches all rows from your `uploads` table in order by filename.  OK.

The second query, nested inside the first, fetches *just one row* (`LIMIT 1`) from the table. It probably fetches the same row each time you run it.

You should eliminate the nested -- second query -- and use the result set from the first query.  Something like this:  (NOTE PLEASE, I HAVEN'T DEBUGGED THIS, THAT'S UP TO YOU.)

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM uploads ORDER BY filename ASC";
$select_uploads = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_uploads)) {

    $id = $row['id'];
    $filename = $row['filename'];
    $filetype = $row['filetype'];
    $filesize = $row['filesize'];
    ?>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="thumbnail text-center">
            <div class="caption">
                <p class="filename"><small><?php echo $filename; ?></small></p>
                <p><a name="download" href="download.php?filename=<?php echo $filenae ;?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" role="button"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Preuzmi</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Some suggestions.

1. try to indent your code so you can see the nesting structure at a glance.
2. get the download part of your project working before you implement the delete part.

Comment: That worked, I eliminated second query and user $filename from first query except $file variable from the second and work fine. Seems I complicate too much. Thanks O. Jones.